# Difference handling virtualhost http and https

Tags: http, ssl, https, virtualhost

I have this VirtualHost file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/dir
    ServerName www.example.com
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/example.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/example.key
    <Directory /var/www/dir>
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

When I browse to the following example links I have this result:

```
1. URL http://www.example.com loads fine.
2. URL http://example.com loads incorrect.
3. URL https://www.example.com loads fine.
4. URL https://example.com loads fine.
```

Now, I know how to correct bullet **2**. My question is: Why does bullet 2 need a seperate VirtualHost like this one,

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

but under SSL it loads fine.

Answer (score 0):

change

> ```
>   <VirtualHost *:80>
>       ServerName www.example.com
>       Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com
>     </VirtualHost>
>
> <VirtualHost *:443>
> DocumentRoot /var/www/dir
> ServerName www.example.com
> SSLEngine on
> SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/example.crt
> SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/example.key
> <Directory /var/www/dir>
>     AllowOverride All
> </Directory>
>   </VirtualHost>
> ```

to

> ```
> <VirtualHost *:80>
> ServerName example.com
> ServerAlias www.example.com
> Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com
>   </VirtualHost>
>
> <VirtualHost *:443>
> DocumentRoot /var/www/dir
> ServerName example.com
> ServerAlias www.example.com
> SSLEngine on
> SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/example.crt
> SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/example.key
> <Directory /var/www/dir>
>     AllowOverride All
> </Directory>
>  </VirtualHost>
> ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and I understand that this technique works, but why did 'ServerName www.example.com' anyways work for the ssl virtualhost if I visit the link hhttps://example.com?